# How to enable resize grips in Unity-2D?

Tags: unity-2d, resize, gtk3

How do you enable resize grips in Unity-2D (or any non-Compiz setup) for GTK 3?

In Oneiric, you could add the following to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css:

```
* { -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: true; }
```

And for GTK 2 (which still works in precise):

```
style "default-style" {
GtkWindow::resize-grip-height = 15
GtkWindow::resize-grip-width = 15 }
class "GtkWidget" style "default-style"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Add the following to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
* {
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-default: true;
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-width: 15;
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-height: 15;
}
```